# Overlap two tensors of different size based on an offset in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following structure:

```
torch.Size([channels, width, height])
```

Let's say I have a tensor `a`

```
torch.Size([4, 512, 512])
```

And tensor `b`

```
torch.Size([4, 100, 100])
```

What I would like to do is to create a tensor `c` that is the result of "placing" tensor `b` on an arbitrary (width, height) coordinate offset of tensor `a`. For example, let's say I would like to place tensor `b` on (300,100) of tensor `a`

So for tensor `a`'s width between the 300-400 position, the values on tensor `a` should be replaced by the 100 values of tensor `b` width.

For tensor `a`'s height between the 100-200 position, the values of tensor `a` should be replaced by the 100 values of tensor `b` height.

I would also like to choose for which channels I want to do this substitution and for which channels I would keep tensor `a`'s value

(PS: The image is just an easy to illustrate example, but I would like to do it in a more generalisable way, so I'm no interested in converting to PIL, using `PIL.paste` and back to tensor but I would like to do all operations directly with)

Answer (score 1):

This function would be fragile without a bunch of pre-conditions to catch for size mismatches, but I think this is basically what you're describing:

```py
def place(a: torch.Tensor, b: torch.Tensor, 
          height: int, width: int, 
          channels: list[int]) -> torch.Tensor:
    """create a tensor ``c`` that is the result of 
    "placing" tensor ``b`` on an arbitrary (height, width) 
    coordinate offset of tensor ``a``,
    for only the specified ``channels``
    """
    channels_b, height_b, width_b  = b.size()
    c = a.clone().detach()
    for channel in channels:
        c[channel, 
          height:height + height_b,
          width:width + width_b] = b[channel]
    return c
```

Comment: Looks great. I was wondering whether it would be a fully custom one or if there were torch functions for this use-case

Comment: Regarding sizing mismatches there should be the simplest condition that if parts of b are out-of-bounds they simply get ignored